# Fresh install of Ubuntu 21.04 freezes within minutes of booting (maybe related to updates)

Tags: freeze

I just installed Ubuntu on my "new" work laptop, a ThinkPad E470. It has frozen on me multiple times. It even froze during the installation process the first time, but the second time it installed fine. The first time, I connected to wifi and turned on updates, and the second time I didn't connect to wifi thinking that may be the culprit.

Once I got it installed, it constantly froze as soon as I got to the desktop. A few times, I got to use it for a few minutes before freezing. The very last time I tried it, Ubuntu Software wouldn't open. I ran apt update and apt upgrade, and as soon as I got to 1% of the upgrade, it froze again. Then I quickly tried one final time, and it froze before I could even open a terminal to try upgrading again.

I think that shows that it's likely related to installing updates. No idea what I can try to fix it. I also tried Pop!OS 20.10 before vanilla Ubuntu 21.04, and it also had freezing issues, so it's not an isolated incident either.

Comment: How hot is the machine running? One of the only reasons I have seen a fresh installation lock up — aside from catastrophic hardware failure — is due to excessive heat. If the temperature of the unit is fine, then it'll be something hardware related that needs to be tracked down, such as a severely worn SSD, voltage irregularities, or even a loose stick of RAM.

Comment: I don't think it's hardware because Windows on the device does not have any issues.